# O que faz a função "do" no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, loop, while, controle-de-fluxo

Pesquisei muito e não encontro a funcionalidade do `do` em JavaScript. Exemplo:

```
function b(a, b) {
    do a = a[b]; while (a && 1 !== a.nodeType);
    return a
}
```

Comment: Referência para a documentação do JavaScript, pela MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference

Comment: Obrigado. Existe alguma em português?

Comment: Sim! Só trocar a linguagem da página para pt-BR ou acessar diretamente [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O mesmo que em outras linguagens, é só um controle de fluxo. Ela é uma marcação para um laço saber onde ele começa. Ele é considerado um *label*. Note que não é uma função, é uma palavra-chave que determina o que o código deve fazer, podemos dizer que é um comando.

Ele é usado em um `while` que podemos chamar de invertido. Ou seja, primeiro entra no laço, sem condição alguma, executa todo ele e no seu final é que é feita uma verificação se deve continuar ou não repetindo este laço. Se a decisão for por continuar então a repetição e volta exatamente para linha do `do`. Portanto o laço sempre será executado pelo menos uma vez.

Sem ele, usando o `while` normal, pode ser que nem a primeira vez seja executado, se a condição for falsa.

Dá para viver sem ele, mas o código pode ficar mais confuso, nada grave, mas é possível que tenha que fazer "malabarismos" ou usar uma variável de *flag* para que a primeira vez execute garantidamente.

As chaves foram omitidas porque o bloco de código só tem uma linha, então é uma forma simplificada. Em geral é melhor evitar esse estilo, fica mais difícil ler. Poderia fazer em uma linha com chaves:

```
do { a = a[b]; } while (a && 1 !== a.nodeType);
```

De forma mais fácil de entender:

```
do { //marca o ínico do laço
    a = a[b];  //faz o que tem que fazer
} while (a && a.nodeType !== 1); //só agora verificará se deve repetir
```

Sem o `do`:

```
a = a[b];
while (a && a.nodeType !== 1) { //a condição é a mesma, só é executada em outro momento
    a = a[b];
} //aqui marca o fim, certamente voltará para o início para decidir se continuará
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/Do.js).

Sempre que quiser saber algo sobre JavaScript a [MDN pode ser considerada a documentação oficial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while).

Comment: +1 pela observação da recomendação para sempre utilizar as chaves. Deixe o código "científico" (ou gato passeando no teclado) para os _minifiers_.

Answer (score 10):

Isso é simplesmente um laço/ciclo `do while`, mas apenas com uma linha de código logo não leva as chaves `{` e `}`.

Normalmente seria escrito assim:

```
do {
    //codigo a repetir no laço/ciclo
} while (condicaoDeFim);
```

Se só tens uma linha podes escrever assim:

```
do /*unica linha de código*/ while (condicaoDeFim);
```

Logo o código apresentado poderia ser escrito assim:

```
do {
    a = a[b]; 
} while (a && 1 !== a.nodeType);
```

Answer (score 6):

Só complementando as outras respostas, e para ajudar no entendimento:

```
do /*faça algo*/ while /*enquanto uma condição seja verdadeira*/
```

:)

Answer (score 3):

A função `do` deve precedir o `while`. Ela serve para que o código seja executado uma vez no mínimo, caso a condição do while seja falsa.

Coloquei exemplos para demonstrar o uso do `do`.

> [Link da documentação](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_dowhile.asp)

Exemplo:

```js
var i = 0;

// Exemplo onde será executado normalmente até que a condição seja falsa e pare
do {
  console.log("i é igual a : %d", i);
  i++;
} while (i < 5);

// Exemplo onde o while é falso, mas será executado do do
var i = 5;
do {
  console.log("A condição (%d<5) é: %s", i, (i < 5) ? 'Verdadeira' : 'Falsa');
  console.log("i é igual a : %d", i);
  i++;
} while (i < 5);

// Sem o do, não será executado nenhuma vez pois a condição é falsa
while (i < 5) {
  console.log('Este bloco não será executado pois %d é menor que 5', i);
}
```